# Identify a Space Opera comics featuring Uranium Theft from moon

Tags: story-identification, comics

Long ago, I read a western comics in my school library. It wasn't kind of from a comic series. It was thick and had library binding. You can call it graphical novel. The genre was Space Opera and it looked kind of Dan Dare. Here are details I remember from a story (there were lots of independent stories in it):

1. There was a Uranium mining facility on the moon (not sure it was Earth's moon or not). A guy (probably, an employee of the facility) used to steal Uranium on regular basis.
2. When authorities came to know about this Uranium theft, he escaped with his ship. The ship was small, kind of shuttle pods of Star Trek.
3. Our heroes (who used to wear red uniform) pursued the thief in a Starship. The Starship was big and kind of *Pillar of Autumn* from Halo.
4. According to scans, our heroes came to know that the thief went down on a planet. So, they put the Starship in the orbit.
5. Just after that, they got shot by a ground artillery which disabled lots of systems. To fix the Starship, they needed to pick rocks with certain crystals and compounds. They went down with shuttle.
6. Some primordial humans/aliens tried to stop them using primitive weapons. Our heroes fired Ray Gun on the ground and grass caught fire. Then, those primordial humans/aliens screamed "Another God" and bowed down.
7. There was a fight between them and aliens with round soccer ball head. The ray guns weren't working on them. But, our heroes found a solution. They wielded their weapon (a stick with a spherical orb on the top) which created fear in them.
8. In the end, they took down the artillery, collected the rock (they also had tricorder type handheld device using which they scanned the contents of a rock), and captured the thief.

I may be mixing two different stories from the same book. If that's the case, one story should be points 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8.3 and another story should be point 5, 7, 8.1, 8.2.

Can you please identify the book?