# First reference to extraterrestrial life forms who weren't considered Gods in sci-fi?

Tags: aliens, history-of

Extraterrestrials/aliens form a major part of science fiction.  I know there are myths going back to ancient times of aliens, but I was wondering **what the first reference in the actual science-fiction literature** (ancient is accepted) is **to life existing on another planet** (not necessarily visiting Earth)?  They **cannot** be considered to be Gods in that particular piece of literature. The only other restriction is that **they did *not* originate on Earth**.

Just for your interest, here is a [related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85058/which-sci-fi-work-introduced-the-concept-of-advanced-aliens-mistaken-as-gods), but not a dupe; I'm specifically asking about the first sci-fi story to introduce the concept of aliens where they weren't considered to be Gods.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I fails to see what's wrong with this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first reference to extraterrestrials aside from extraterrestrials acting as Gods (which gets into murky territory) is the Roman *[True History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_History)* back in the 2nd Century where a human visits the Moon to find it is populated.

Slightly later we have the 10th Century *The Tale of the Bamboo Cutter* from Japan and the medieval Arabic *The The Adventures of Bulukiya (from the One Thousand and One Nights)* ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraterrestrials_in_fiction))

Following the development of the heliocentric concept of the solar system, the idea of extraterrestrials really 'took off' (so to speak). ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraterrestrials_in_fiction#Early_modern))

In terms of modern science-fiction, one of the most famous references was H.G. Well's *The War of the Worlds* involving a Martian invasion.

Further references to aliens throughout science fiction history can be found in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraterrestrials_in_fiction).